# Use object instead of column name in dplyr's group_by

Tags: r, dplyr, evaluation

I would like to have an input that I can state before like so:

```
GroupVar2 = recommendation$Product

prof.prod <- recommendation %>% group_by(GroupVar2) %>% summarise(value = 
sum(Revenue)) %>% filter(value==max(value))
```

However, I get the error that the  "Column `GroupVar2` is unknown".

Does anyone know how to use 'recommendation$Product' specified in a placeholder?

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. See [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4996248) for what this would mean in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error arises because `group_by` is looking for column `GroupVar2` in the data frame `recommendation`.

If you need to use the placeholder `GroupVar2`, you can use **`!!`** to *unquote* the argument in `group_by`:

```
group_by(!! GroupVar2)
```

In this way the input is evaluated.

Comment: Thanks Sven! But I would like to use it in a sat up that I can use for multiple data sets. So if the column is not named 'recommendation' I would like it to work still.